# Combining LOOKUP and OFFSET

Tags: excel, excel-formula, offset, lookup, vlookup

I would like to offset the last entry in my data by one week. For example, I just created this example data:

```
day value
1   4
2   3
3   5
4   6
5   1
6   3
7   9
8   5
```

To find the last entry in the dataset, I use the lookup function:

```
 =LOOKUP(9.99E+307,b1:b10)
```

which will return the value `5`. (In case that notation is not familiar, `9.99E+307` is the largest number that can be written in Excel).

I would like then to compare this value to last week's value, and thus offset the last entry by 7. I see that OFFSET asks for: *offset(reference,rows,cols)* but using:

```
=OFFSET(LOOKUP(9.99E+307,b1:b10),-7,0)
```

does not seem to work (it returns an error).

What could be the problem?

Comment: Thank you everyone for all the helpful answers, I really appreciate it. I will use the look-up oriented one as that is the function that I am most comfortable with.

Comment: Thanks for the accept. For the record, pnuts put forth a more elegant solution. If you haven't yet, take some time to explore both `INDEX` and `MATCH`. They can be extremely useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not change the lookup to look for the last day in the list?

This formula will return the last day value (8 in your data above):

```
=LOOKUP(9.99E+307,A1:A10)
```

You can then use this formula to return the last value for that day (5 in your data above):

```
=VLOOKUP(LOOKUP(9.99E+307,A1:A10),A1:B10,2,FALSE)
```

If you wanted to get the value for 7 days earlier just subtract 7 from the results of the LOOKUP formula like this (will return 4 - day 1 value in your data above):

```
=VLOOKUP(LOOKUP(9.99E+307,A1:A10)-7,A1:B10,2,FALSE)
```

Answer (score 2):

@user3561813 has explained why, a solution might be:

```
=INDEX(B:B,MATCH(1E+100,B:B)-7)
```

[MATCH](https://support.office.microsoft.com/en-gb/article/MATCH-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca?CorrelationId=8494088c-0ee5-46fc-9b4b-f0915a4ae632&ui=en-US&rs=en-GB&ad=GB) finds the position (row number) of last entry in ColumnB, `-7` steps up seven rows and [INDEX](https://support.office.microsoft.com/en-gb/article/INDEX-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a?CorrelationId=83da8393-d0a4-44ff-9cc0-c2008dd1c3d6&ui=en-US&rs=en-GB&ad=GB) finds the content of that row in ColumnB.

Comment: I don't quite understand how this gets the trick done yet, but this does indeed work nicely.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use a single `LOOKUP` function with the "return vector" offset by 7 rows, e.g.

`=LOOKUP(9.99E+307,B8:B100,B1:B93)`

Answer (score 1):

The `Reference` is the `OFFSET` function refers to a Range object (a cell). The result of your `Lookup` function is a numeric value, in this case 5. You can't `OFFSET` a numeric value.

Have you considered using VBA?